# Reading an ORC file in Java

Tags: java, hadoop, orc

How do you read an ORC file in Java? I'm wanting to read in a small file for some unit test output verification, but I can't find a solution.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Came across this and implemented one myself recently

```
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcFile;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.Reader;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.RecordReader;

import org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.StructField;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.StructObjectInspector;

import java.util.List;

public class OrcFileDirectReaderExample {
    public static void main(String[] argv)
    {
        try {
            Reader reader = OrcFile.createReader(HdfsFactory.getFileSystem(), new Path("/user/hadoop/000000_0"));
            StructObjectInspector inspector = (StructObjectInspector)reader.getObjectInspector();
            System.out.println(reader.getMetadata());
            RecordReader records = reader.rows();
            Object row = null;
            //These objects are the metadata for each column.  They give you the type of each column and can parse it unless you
            //want to parse each column yourself
            List fields = inspector.getAllStructFieldRefs();
            for(int i = 0; i < fields.size(); ++i) {
                System.out.print(((StructField)fields.get(i)).getFieldObjectInspector().getTypeName() + '\t');
            }

            while(records.hasNext())
            {
                row = records.next(row);
                List value_lst = inspector.getStructFieldsDataAsList(row);
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                //iterate over the fields
                //Also fields can be null if a null was passed as the input field when processing wrote this file
                for(Object field : value_lst) {
                    if(field != null)
                        builder.append(field.toString());
                    builder.append('\t');
                }
                //this writes out the row as it would be if this were a Text tab seperated file
                System.out.println(builder.toString());
            }
        }catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: This saved me! Worked perfectly!

Comment: What would be the dependency for HdfsFactory class?

Answer (score 0):

As per Apache [Wiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+ORC), ORC file format was introduced in Hive 0.11.

So you will need Hive packages in your project source path to read ORC files. The package for the same are

```
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.Reader;
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcFile
```

Comment: I have tried implementing a solution using these already but haven't had much luck.

Answer (score 0):

read orc testcase

```java
    @Test
    public void read_orc() throws Exception {
        //todo do kerberos auth
        String orcPath = "hdfs://user/hive/warehouse/demo.db/orc_path";
        //load hdfs conf
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        conf.addResource(getClass().getResource("/hdfs-site.xml"));
        conf.addResource(getClass().getResource("/core-site.xml"));
        FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
        // custom read column
        List<String> columns = Arrays.asList("id", "title");
        final List<Map<String, Object>> maps = OrcUtil.readOrcFile(fs, orcPath, columns);
        System.out.println(new Gson().toJson(maps));
    }
```

`OrcUtil` to read orc path with special columns

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.PathFilter;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcFile;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcSerde;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcSplit;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcStruct;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.Reader;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeException;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.StructField;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.StructObjectInspector;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InputSplit;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.RecordReader;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reporter;

public class OrcUtil {
    
    public static List<Map<String, Object>> readOrcFile(FileSystem fs, String orcPath, List<String> readColumns)
            throws IOException, SerDeException {
        JobConf jobConf = new JobConf();
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : fs.getConf()) {
            jobConf.set(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }
        
        FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(jobConf, orcPath);
        FileInputFormat.setInputPathFilter(jobConf, ((PathFilter) path1 -> true).getClass());
        
        InputSplit[] splits = new OrcInputFormat().getSplits(jobConf, 1);
        InputFormat<NullWritable, OrcStruct> orcInputFormat = new OrcInputFormat();
        
        List<Map<String, Object>> rows = new ArrayList<>();
        for (InputSplit split : splits) {
            OrcSplit orcSplit = (OrcSplit) split;
            System.out.printf("read orc split %s%n", ((OrcSplit) split).getPath());
            StructObjectInspector inspector = getStructObjectInspector(orcSplit.getPath(), jobConf, fs);
            List<? extends StructField> readFields = inspector.getAllStructFieldRefs()
                    .stream().filter(e -> readColumns.contains(e.getFieldName())).collect(Collectors.toList());
            // 49B file is empty
            if (orcSplit.getLength() > 49) {
                RecordReader<NullWritable, OrcStruct> recordReader = orcInputFormat.getRecordReader(orcSplit, jobConf, Reporter.NULL);
                NullWritable key = recordReader.createKey();
                OrcStruct value = recordReader.createValue();
                while (recordReader.next(key, value)) {
                    Map<String, Object> entity = new HashMap<>();
                    for (StructField field : readFields) {
                        entity.put(field.getFieldName(), inspector.getStructFieldData(value, field));
                    }
                    rows.add(entity);
                }
            }
        }
        return rows;
    }
    
    private static StructObjectInspector getStructObjectInspector(Path path, JobConf jobConf, FileSystem fs)
            throws IOException, SerDeException {
        OrcFile.ReaderOptions readerOptions = OrcFile.readerOptions(jobConf);
        readerOptions.filesystem(fs);
        Reader reader = OrcFile.createReader(path, readerOptions);
        String typeStruct = reader.getObjectInspector().getTypeName();
        System.out.println(typeStruct);
        List<String> columnList = parseColumnAndType(typeStruct);
        String[] fullColNames = new String[columnList.size()];
        String[] fullColTypes = new String[columnList.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < columnList.size(); ++i) {
            String[] temp = columnList.get(i).split(":");
            fullColNames[i] = temp[0];
            fullColTypes[i] = temp[1];
        }
        Properties p = new Properties();
        p.setProperty("columns", StringUtils.join(fullColNames, ","));
        p.setProperty("columns.types", StringUtils.join(fullColTypes, ":"));
        OrcSerde orcSerde = new OrcSerde();
        orcSerde.initialize(jobConf, p);
        return (StructObjectInspector) orcSerde.getObjectInspector();
    }
    
    private static List<String> parseColumnAndType(String typeStruct) {
        int startIndex = typeStruct.indexOf("<") + 1;
        int endIndex = typeStruct.lastIndexOf(">");
        typeStruct = typeStruct.substring(startIndex, endIndex);
        
        List<String> columnList = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> splitList = Arrays.asList(typeStruct.split(","));
        Iterator<String> it = splitList.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            StringBuilder current = new StringBuilder(it.next());
            String currentStr = current.toString();
            boolean left = currentStr.contains("(");
            boolean right = currentStr.contains(")");
            if (!left && !right) {
                columnList.add(currentStr);
                continue;
            }
            if (left && right) {
                columnList.add(currentStr);
                continue;
            }
            if (left && !right) {
                while (it.hasNext()) {
                    String next = it.next();
                    current.append(",").append(next);
                    if (next.contains(")")) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                columnList.add(current.toString());
            }
        }
        return columnList;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this for getting ORCFile rowcount...

```
private long getRowCount(FileSystem fs, String fName) throws Exception {
    long tempCount = 0;
    Reader rdr = OrcFile.createReader(fs, new Path(fName));
    StructObjectInspector insp = (StructObjectInspector) rdr.getObjectInspector();
    Iterable<StripeInformation> iterable = rdr.getStripes();
    for(StripeInformation stripe:iterable){
        tempCount = tempCount + stripe.getNumberOfRows();
    }
    return tempCount;
}   

//fName is hdfs path to file.
long rowCount = getRowCount(fs,fName);
```

Comment: Can you mention the imports, the external libraries? The function alone is difficult to reuse unless these are mentioned.